# raspberry python imgproc module saving

Tags: python, image, raspberry-pi, python-imaging-library

Hi i using a python library called `imgproc` which make it so that i can take images from a webcam onto a raspberry-pi. But i don't know how to save it to a `.jpg` file. I have researched everywhere but i can't find the answer anywhere.The link to the library is [here](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/image_processing/). I have tried everything but i don't have a pi-cam which is the proper method. Hers my current code:

```
import socket
import time
from imgproc import *
cam = Camera(320, 240)
host = "example.com"
port = 8888
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ri = socket.gethostbyname(host)
s.connect((ri , port))
x = True
while x:
    img = cam.grabImage()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible by using, e.g., PIL or another similar library. However, if you want it to be fast, there are some problems.

The challenge comes from the `imgproc` API, which does not seem to allow any quick access to the image data itself. The only method for this is by using the `__getitem__` method of the `Image` object, for example `img[x,y]`. This looks very much like `numpy` arrays, but unfortunately they do not have anything else in common.

`imgproc` is a very thin wrapper built on a C library. It is quite instructive to have a look at `imgproc.py`, as it shows all the available bindings.

Most probably you will have to construct the image pixel-by-pixel, which is not very fast. For example:

```
img_array = numpy.array([ [ img[x,y] for x in range(img.width) ] for y in range(img.height) ] , dtype='uint8')
```

Once you have the image array, you can convert it into a PIL image and save the image:

```
pil_img = Image.fromarray(img_array)
pil_img.save('my_image.jpg')
```

In order to do this, you need both `numpy` and `Image` modules (PIL). This method is not very fast. The alternative is to create an empty `numpy` array and populate it:

```
img_array = numpy.empty((img.height, img.width, 3), dtype='uint8')
for y in range(img.height):
    for x in range(img.height):
        img_array[y,x] = img[x,y]
```

Only testing will reveal which one is less slow.

In principle, it is not hideously difficult to augment the library by adding bit more powerful wrapper functions around the library to make it return the binary buffer contents in a better format, but doing it requires knowledge both in C and in python.

Comment: If you are happy with PNG images, you could use PyPNG. It is a pure-python module, so installation is very easy, you just need to copy a single module to wherever you want to use it. Of course, PNG images take a lot more space.

Comment: I suggest you create a new question, e.g. "How to save image in python 3.4 without using bumpy or PIL". I know it is relatively simple to do in netPBM or BMP, but there may be others who can give you better answers if you open a new question!